# Is the /tmp some special?

Tags: php, tmp

Ubuntu 18.04

/ on ext4

I create a file in /tmp by php script. Ok, I see it by cat. But php file_exists() on another script return FALSE.

I create a file in /var/www by the same script. Yes! file_exists() return TRUE.

What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess, you are running PHP in a service where the systemd service file specifies `PrivateTmp=yes`

See also

- https://muras.eu/2017/12/06/apache-ubuntu-systemd-privatetmp/
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/systemd.exec.5.html

> PrivateTmp=
> Takes a boolean argument. If true, sets up a new file system namespace for the
> executed processes and mounts private /tmp and /var/tmp directories inside it that is
> not shared by processes outside of the namespace.

Comment: Thanks. Is it this.
I think that the problem resolved. It works now.

Comment: Heh. It's not enough. PHP CLI has different /tmp anyway.
Even if set `sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"` in both apache and cli php.ini

Comment: Interesting.  A quick search shows there are several factors that affect PHP.  Maybe this article will help: https://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/where-is-tmp/

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I saw these effects, but I think that system file cache matter. At any rate, I could not write to one file from two CLI scripts more often than once per second. If more often - only from one script data be stored to file. It if place the file to any dir. If to /tmp - impossible at all.

Comment: I got the impression that every shell run string has your own /tmp. Even if it differs only by params.